# Selecting from two tables, limiting by the first

Tags: mysql, limit

I've been looking for the solution for several days, and I'm starting to feel like a real idiot.

I have two tables.

```
entries                       link
+----------+-------+-----+    +----------+------+
| date     | title | txt |    | date     | tag  |
+==========+=======+=====+    +==========+======+
|2014-01-01| titl1 | txt1|    |2014-01-01| tag1 |
|2014-01-02| titl2 | txt2|    |2014-01-01| tag2 |
|2014-01-03| titl3 | txt3|    |2014-01-01| tag3 |
|2014-01-04| titl4 | txt4|    |2014-01-02| tag1 |
|2014-01-05| titl4 | txt4|    |2014-01-02| tag2 |
|2014-01-06| titl4 | txt4|    |2014-01-03| tag1 |
|2014-01-07| titl4 | txt4|    |2014-01-04| tag2 |
|2014-01-08| titl4 | txt4|    |2014-01-04| tag4 |
+----------+-------+-----+    +~~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~+ 'link' continues
```

I want * from 'entries', ordered by 'date', limited by 4, as well as **all** corresponding 'tag's from 'link' for each entry.

'date' from 'entries' is a primary key, if that's important. 'link' doesn't have primary keys, as there will be duplicates of both 'date' and 'tag'.

Posting here was a last resort, as I generally hate relying on help to get something done, but I'm completely run out of mental capacity to keep trying.

I've got this query, which grabs one entry and the corresponding tag, and limits by 4, but it doesn't grab /all/ tags per entry.

```
SELECT date, title, txt
FROM entries
WHERE date IN (
    SELECT date
    FROM link
    WHERE date = entries.date
)
LIMIT 4
```

If I 'reverse' this and try,

```
SELECT date, tag
FROM link
WHERE date IN (
    SELECT date
    FROM entries
    WHERE date = link.date
)
LIMIT 4
```

It limits by four rows from 'link'.

I really hope I've explained what I want properly. If I wasn't clear, I can try again.

Comment: The problem now if that for example `2014-01-01` has 3 related entries in `link` table.  In a JOIN query that combines data from both tables, this would result in 3 records. SOo, do you want the three tags from 2014-01-01 and the first tag from 2014-01-02 in your limit of 4 or are you trying to limit the date range to for records and get all tags for each of the 4 dates (which would require some aggregation)?

Comment: All tags for each of the four entries. I'll edit the main post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what I wanted with,

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT date AS date
    FROM entries
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 4
) AS ent, link
WHERE ent.date = link.date
```

This gives me entries and all their tags, and limits to four entries, without cutting the tags off.

It outputs a pattern similar to:

```
2014-01-04 tag4
2014-01-04 tag2
2014-01-03 tag1
2014-01-02 tag2
2014-01-02 tag1
2014-01-01 tag3
2014-01-01 tag2
2014-01-01 tag1
```

Which is what I wanted.

I took a few hours to just calm down and just walk away from the code, and sometimes, that's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are asking. 
This query returns the first four entries and their associated tags

```
select a.date, a.title, a.txt , l.tag
from
(select date, title, txt 
from entries
limit 4) a,
link l
where l.date = a.date
```

Not sure what rownum(oracle) is in mysql, guessing it's limit based on your post.

Answer (score 0):

The following query would give you a maximum of 4 dates (in ascending order) with all associated tags concatenated into a comma-separated string in the `tags` calculated field.  Of course there is no `WHERE` condition shown (I did not see a meaningful WHERE in your question), so I imagine you would want to add one to make this meaningful (i.e. not returning the first 4 dates every time).  It was also not clear what sort order you wanted to use.  It is generally bad form to use `LIMIT` without a related `ORDER BY` clause, as you can get unexpected results. I have assumed an ascending sort based on date here.

```
SELECT
    e.`date` AS `date`,
    e.title AS title,
    e.txt AS txt,
    GROUP_CONTAT(l.tag) AS tags
FROM entries AS e
LEFT JOIN link AS l
    ON e.`date` = l.`date`
ORDER BY e.`date` ASC
WHERE ???
LIMIT 4
```

Note: Use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` if you only want `entries` records that have some related records in `link`. You also may want to consider using a string other than the reserved word `date` for your column names.